# Update query where value is null not giving result back

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm working on a little java crud api which performs crud operations on a mySql database. Everything works except when I try to update a table where a field is null.

The table has 4 fields: the first (`id_tess_fk`) and the second (`tag_fk`) are two foreign keys, the third (`data_start`) is set as default current timestamp and the fourth (`data_end`) is again a date which is null when the row is created and will be updated to the actual date when input is given.

I've tried using `IS NULL` syntax and `=null` but I always get the same empty result. If I omit this in the where condition, the query returns something but it's not what I actually need because I need to update just the row that meets the condition.

What am I doing wrong?

```
case "/nol": stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT data_start FROM noleggi WHERE id_tess_fk=? AND tag_fk=? AND data_end IS null ;");
                    stmt.setString(1,id_tess);
                    stmt.setString(2,tag);


                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    //while(rs.next())
                    //{

                        java.util.Date data_start = rs.getDate("data_start");



                        int sec_used = Math.toIntExact((data_start.getTime() - data_end.getTime()) / 1000);

                        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT sec_cred FROM utenti WHERE id_tess=?;");
                        stmt.setString(1, id_tess);

                        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                        sec_cred = rs.getInt("sec_cred");


                        sec_cred -= sec_used;


                        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE `utenti` SET `sec_cred`=? WHERE `id_tess_fk`=?;");
                        stmt.setInt(1, sec_cred);
                        stmt.setString(2, id_tess);
                        stmt.executeUpdate();

                        java.sql.Timestamp timestamp_data_end = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

                        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE noleggi SET data_end=? WHERE id_tess_fk=? AND tag_fk=? AND data_end=?;");
                        stmt.setTimestamp(1, timestamp_data_end);
                        stmt.setString(2, id_tess);
                        stmt.setString(3, tag);
                        //stmt.setNull(4,Types.NULL);
                        value = stmt.executeUpdate();

                        if (value != 0)
                        {
                            jsonObject.put("response_code", 201);
                            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

                        } else
                        {
                            jsonObject.put("response_code", 400);
                            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                        }

                        response.getWriter().println(jsonArray);

                    //}
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                    break;`
```

Comment: In SQL, nothing is equal to `NULL`, not even `NULL`.  An `IS NULL` condition is the correct way to test for null.

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the statement. Make sure you have an exception handler that properly prints stack trace. Show the code where you actually execute this statement. Are you sure the values in `id_tess` and `tag` are exactly those that are in the database?

Comment: If you omit the `AND data_end IS NULL` condition then you must get a superset of the results that you can get by adding that or any other additional `AND` condition.  Do the wanted rows from that result set actually have null `data_end` dates?

Comment: What is the data type of data_end?

Comment: @RealSkeptic My code is a simple servlet which contains the usual doGet, doPost, doPut and doDelete methods. The code inside each one of these methods is wrapped in a try-catch to manage SQL and JSON exception. In each one of these methods, I loop through an enumeration to fetch the request parameters and values in order to assign each one of them to a variable. Then I use a switch-case to manage the different endpoints. I put the code in the first post.

Comment: @JamesJithin the data type of data_end is datetime and it can be null.

Comment: [java.sql.PreparedStatement#setNull(int,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int))

Comment: Well then, the answer to "What am I doing wrong?" seems to be expecting those dates to be null.  Seeing as how they are not, in fact, null, their rows are of course not selected when you add an `IS NULL` criterion for them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh i'm terribly sorry, I misunderstood your question :-S YES, the row I want to select has data_end set to 'NULL'.

Comment: ... and to be perfectly clear, the row you're trying to retrieve is among those returned if you remove the `AND data_end IS NULL` criterion while keeping everything else the same?

Comment: @JohnBollinger well, the problem is that the values in the id_tess_fk and tag_fk together could be repeated in more than one row, so removing the "and data_end Is null" condition would return ALL the rows that contain that couple of values and that's not what I want because I want just the row (or to be precise, just the "data_start" field value) where data_end is set to null, in order to update it.

Comment: @Slowww, I understand that you require a more specific query than the one without the `IS NULL` condition.  What I'm trying to confirm, beyond a shadow of a doubt, is that if you leave off the `IS NULL` then the rows you want are among those you get, and contain the NULLs you expect.  In fact, best would be to test this with Java and confirm via with the mysql command-line client.  Because the combination of claims you've made sounds extremely unlikely -- they seem to boil down to MySQL or Connector/J being broken, whereas it's far more likely that something is wrong with the data.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You were right: the problem was related to the type. I used to fetch "data_start" using getDate instead of getTimestamp! Now it works! Thank you all.